# Jenkins+Gitlab plugin stopped sending emails on failures after upgrading Jenkins to v2

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

We have a Jenkins server with the Gitlab plugin installed. It was working fine before -- a push to Gitlab would tell Jenkins to build, and if there were any errors, Gitlab was notified and the person who pushed would get an email notification.

After upgrading Jenkins to v2 and updating all plugins, we're no longer getting emails. The builds are still being triggered though.

I can see "gitlab web hook triggered for ..." and "main build action completed: FAILURE" in the Jenkins log, but nothing about a failure to notify gitlab about the failure.

I didn't set this up originally, so I'm looking for pointers on where to look. Are there any changes I have to make for the v2 upgrade? Are there any logs that would have more info?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was the problem I was having:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/egzdOBAjrds

Bug report:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37422

The upgraded ruby-runtime was somehow preventing the post-build actions section from working.